# description list and macrocode indentation

Tags: description, docstrip, l3doc

With l3doc, when using macrocode inside a description list, it is displayed with an extra indentation, how to remove it ?

Here is the dtx for a MWE

```
% \iffalse meta-comment
%<*driver>
\ExplSyntaxOff
\documentclass{l3doc}
\begin{document}
  \DocInput{\jobname.dtx}
\end{document}
%</driver>
% \fi
%    \begin{macrocode}
Aligned left
%    \end{macrocode}
% \begin{description}
% \item[item] item description
%    \begin{macrocode}
Unwanted indentation
%    \end{macrocode}
% \end{description}
```

The output

[image]

Comment: You are in the list so there is the indent for that: I assume you _want_ it as you've got a rather odd input setup.

Comment: I would like to have the same horizontal space between the "1" and the word "Aligned" than between the "2" and the word "Unwanted". Outside `macrocode` environment, spacing is Ok. And the line numbers should stay vertically aligned.